# Access Squarespace Brine template blog metadata

Tags: templates, metadata, squarespace

I asked this question nearly a week ago on the [Squarespace Answers forum](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/279450/access-brine-blog-metadata.html) but have received no replies, so forgive me for cross-posting here.

I am trying to follow the instructions for Hiding a blog post's, author and publication date using the Brine template, but I can't find how to access the **Blog: Metadata** it talks about for this template here [Standard grid/list Blog Pages](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/227054767) and here [Brine Site Styles tweaks](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/212838128-Brine-Site-Styles-tweaks)

Apparently the metadata is supposed to be accessible in the Squarespace editor via the **Home > Design > Site Styles** settings, not directly from the blog page itself. However the Site Styles menu does not offer any Blog settings, let alone metadata, as far as I can see.  I'm obviously missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the blog-related styles don't show up by default, and you cannot search for them. To ensure that they appear:

1. navigate to your blog page first (the page with the metadata you want to change), while logged in and editing your site.
2. Then, go to `Design` > `Site Styles`.
3. At this point, the blog-related style settings should be in the list; you can search for them by typing "blog" in the search field in the sidebar. Alternatively, click on the area of the web page that has the blog meta and the settings should appear in the sidebar.

Comment: Thankyou Brandon. So simple when you know how!!

Comment: I have taken the liberty of adding your answer to my question on the Squarespace forum, I hope you don't mind.